# AutoHotkey + Windows 8: Running desktop applications

Tags: windows-8-preview, autohotkey

I've got a simple AHK script:

```
#n::Run notepad.exe
```

If I'm looking at the desktop and hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, I see Notepad. The problem is, if I'm on looking at the Start screen and hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, I get nothing. Notepad opens on the desktop, but doesn't take me to the desktop to see it.

Is that normal behavior? Is there some fancy way to get me to the desktop if I'm currently not already there? Maybe seeing if the active window is `ImmersiveLauncher`, press the Start key? AutoHotkey can do that, right?

**Edit 1**:  I got the logic down, but I quickly realized that the Start key doesn't always take you to the desktop.  From an app, it takes you to the Start screen, and from the Start screen, it takes you to the last app you used.

```
Win8Fix()
{
    WinGetClass, class,  A
    if class = ImmersiveLauncher
        Send, {LWin down}{LWin up}
}

#n::
Win8Fix()
Run notepad.exe
```

Instead of `Send, {LWin down}{LWin up}`, I tried to get creative and press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> which focuses on the system tray, but I couldn't get that working from AHK:

```
if class = ImmersiveLauncher
    Send, {LWin down}{b down}{LWin up}
```

It works in desktop mode, but does nothing in Metro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work, got it from the AHK forums-

```
Win8Fix(ByRef pid)
{
    WinWait ahk_pid %pid%,,5

    if !ErrorLevel ; Didn't time out.
    {
        WinActivate
    }
}

#n::
Run notepad.exe,,,pid
Win8Fix(pid)
return
```

Doesn't work very well for running urls like `#g::Run www.google.com,,,pid` unfortunately, but you can still target a browser's executable and pass www.google.com as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

```
#n::
{
    Run notepad.exe
        WinActivate, Program Manager
}
```

Comment: Indent by four spaces for a code block. Or select it and press `ctrl` + `k`. See [editing help](http://superuser.com/editing-help).

Comment: Oh, and welcome to [su]!

Answer (score 0):

I created a script that can help with that problem, it allows to Open, Minimize or Restore a Window Shortcut, a Window App, a Chrome App or a Chrome shortcut.

It also has some other features like Error catching etc..  the code is here:
https://github.com/JuanmaMenendez/AutoHotkey-script-Open-Show-Apps

**Configuration Examples**

```
F7:: OpenOrShowAppBasedOnExeName("C:\Windows\System32\SnippingTool.exe")

F8:: OpenOrShowAppBasedOnWindowTitle("Gmail", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --app=https://mail.google.com/mail/")
```

I hope you found it helpful ;) ‍♂️⭐